# javascript: toggle event listener with onclick

Tags: javascript

I have this JS function which I'm trying to toggle on and off when clicked on the object with the `myFunc()` function on it. The trouble I'm having is that by the time the code reaches the first `if(myVar)/else` part and tries to do the handler it has already switched the `myVar` variable to `false`. What should I change to correct my logic error?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = true;
        function myFunc(myElement) {
            var ele = myElement;

            var myHandler = function(event) {
                if(myVar) {
                    // do something 
                } else {
                    // do something else 
                }
            }

            if(myVar) {
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', myHandler, false);
                myVar = false;
            } else {
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', myHandler, false);
                myVar = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

...

```
<body>
    <div id="div1" onclick="myFunc(this)"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
var myVar = false;

function myHandler(event) {
  if (myVar) {
    console.log('do something');
  }
}

function myFunc(myElement) {
  var ele = myElement;

  myVar = !myVar;
  if (myVar) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', myHandler, false);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', myHandler, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc(this)">click me</button>
```

Tell me if there is something you're not understanding in this code.

Comment: a little bit modified version of this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why does myHandler need to check the value of myVar? According to your logic, myVar will always be false when myHandler runs, because you're always setting it to false when you add the event listener. myVar will only ever be set to true when you remove the event listener, so myHandler will never run when myVar is true.

You can remove the if(myVar)/else from myHandler since myVar will always be false there.

Comment: myVar changes value when clicked. When JS loads it starts out as true, onclick it changes to false, when clicked again true etc etc. I know that the myHandler runs even when myVar is false because the code inside of it executes. The problem is the code does opposite what from what I want: it skips the first click(doesnt do anything except change the myVar value), it then runs false code block when myVar is true, true code block when myVar is false.

Comment: If you just want it to do the opposite of what it's doing, change the check to if(!myVar)

Comment: It works that way but I feel like this still isn't the correct way of doing it because it should add the event listener and do the first myHandler part when myVar is true, but I guess I will stick to that if I can't find any better way to solve it. The myHandler variable function is one step behind, and the problems arise when I add more divs which use the same onclick event.

Comment: If you want myVar to be false only after the first myHandler run, set it to false inside myHandler after it checks myVar, not after you add the eventHandler.

Comment: It will be in an endless loop of setting the value to true/false then, and does not work properly that way either. As I said, the myHandler variable function is one step behind, and the problems arise when I add more divs which use the same onclick event.

Comment: It will not be in an endless loop if you do exactly what I said. I don't understand what is supposed to qualify as "working properly" here

Comment: If needed I can show you what is working improperly over teamviewer as I would not like to share the full code here. I already tried it the way you said and if I change the myVar inside of myHandler it will keep looping through the myHandler if/else block when I'm moving my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by 2 methods

method 1:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">div</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = false;
        var myHandler = function() {
                myVar = !myVar;
        }
        document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', myHandler);
</script>
```

method2:

```
<body>
    <div onClick="myHandler()">div</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = false;
        var myHandler = function() {
          myVar = !myVar;
        }
</script>
```

hope you have found what you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't work because it isn't the handler which is adding the mousemove event to window, it's the myFunc function. The problem I'm currently having is it seems like the myHandler var is one loop behind, which means it starts functioning after the second click on the div. I could change the myVar to false in myHandler but that is only a short term workaround, as when I decide to add more divs which use the same function things get really messy.